# So how does Master Healer actually work?

Tags: feats, legend

The text on the feat Master Healer reads as follows:

> Benefit: You gain the ability to brew short-lived
>   draughts that duplicate the effects of a Medicine
>   check. To make one, you must pass the corresponding
>   check by ten or more. You may make
>   three draughts per [Scene]. These draughts last
>   until the end of the [Scene] and can be used as
>   part of a move action.

The trouble that I, and my players, are having is that some of the wording seems a bit vague. So, my questions about the feat are as follows:

- What action is it to *create* a draught? Medicine checks take longer than a single move action in many cases.
- Can I use the draught on another character, such as a [Dying] or otherwise helpless ally?
- Can I create a draught that duplicates the effect of identifying a creature with the Medicine skill, and if so how does that even work?

If there's a relevant bit of RAW that can clear up my question, I'd love to hear it. I'm also perfectly happy with errata or developer intent.

Answer (score 2):

I would rule that it takes as long – at least – to brew the draught as it would to make the check (the draught can just be saved for when you need the check result *now*), and I would only allow it for uses of Medicine that involve giving some kind of medical attention to someone.